# How can I declear mips array?

Tags: mips

I would like to declare

int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} in c language as mips.

Here's my code, please give me a solution.

A: .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Is it right?

Comment: What do you think? Did you try running the code to see if it worked?

Comment: Even without code, you can use the debugger to inspect data.  If your environment doesn't allow that, then add a dummy main, and run the simulator to see your initial data.  Inspecting your data before single step debugging is an important step.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's right, then you can use A as the addresss, and A+offset to get the position of every element.